# How to use selenium to open multiple urls from a column in an xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, selenium, loops, url

I am an absolute noob and I have the following scenario: I have an Excel file with a column filled with +4000 URLs each one in a different cell. The url links to a facebook-like page where a user would be asked to set a password. I need to use Python to retrieve each url from the column, open it with Chrome, input the same specified password for all users, and then validate it lands on the home page.

Step by step:

1 Openpyxl opens excel spreadsheet.

2 Find column with urls.

3 Make a list of urls?

4 Get chrome to open the first url.

6 Find password field.

7 Input a password that will be the same one for all users.

8 Confirm it lands on homepage.

9 Loop with all other urls in the column until the end.

10 Preferably get a report to confirm the number of fails if any.

So far this is my code:

```
# I can open the file
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('Test Sheet.xlsx')
type(wb)

# get the name of the sheet I need to work with
print (wb.sheetnames)

<Worksheet "Users">

# this line brings the current urls in my file 
sheet=wb['Users']
for x in range (2,4):
print(x,sheet.cell(row=x,column=3).value)

# output
2 https://firstfacebookpage.com
3 https://secondfacebookpage.com


# I found this other way to retrieve the urls from the excel spreadsheet.
ws = wb['Users']
column = ws['c']  
column_list = [column[x].value for x in range(len(column))]
print (column_list)

# output while having only 2 urls in the test sheet.
['Claim Link', 'https://somefacebookurl.com', 'https://someotherfacebookurl.com', None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

# This login, enter password, verify, close browser, works perfectly if I manually enter the url.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://firstfacebookpage.com")

password_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('inputpassword') 
password_box.send_keys("theonepassword") 
print ("Password entered") 

login_box = driver.find_element_by_id('u_0_9') 
login_box.click() 

print ("Done") 
driver.close() 
print("Finished")
```

Now I can't figure out a way to make the "driver.get" the urls from the spreadsheet and loop over these login steps.  Since my file will have +4000 urls in the column I'd rather have the script do that for me. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: why do you need use selenium to read the Excel File? Can't you read it with out selenium ? Read the excel using python and store it in to List/Array/Set.

Comment: I am using openpyxl to read the excel file and I thought I could make something with it to then have selenium open the urls. I thought modules could communicate with each other but it may be a noob idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with pandas & xlrd,

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException



df = pd.read_excel('myurls.xlsm') # Get all the urls from the excel
mylist = df['urls'].tolist() #urls is the column name

print(mylist) # will print all the urls

# now loop through each url & perform actions.
for url in mylist:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)

    try:
       WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present(),'Timed out waiting for alert.')

       alert = driver.switch_to.alert
       alert.accept()
       print("alert accepted")
    except TimeoutException:
       print("no alert")
    password_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('inputpassword') 
    password_box.send_keys("theonepassword") 
    print ("Password entered")
    login_box = driver.find_element_by_id('u_0_9') 
    login_box.click() 
    driver.close()


print ("Done")
```

Comment: I understand this line mylist = df['Users'].tolist() #urls is the column name is supposed to identify the sheet. My sheet is called 'Users' but it's giving a KeyError. I wanted to copy the error log but it seems to contain more characters than permitted.

Comment: Users is the column name. i have updated the answer. sorry for the confusion

Comment: Now it works with the first url from the list but it stops at the home page the second time the "show notifications - allow - block " appears.  And then it gives an error "Unable to locate element: inputpassword" I guess it's still trying to login at the homepage instead of closing the window and proceeding to the next url on the list. But I have no idea why.

Comment: hmm. the alert was unexpected. Do you want to use the same browser open the url one by one or use a new browser everytime to open the url?  Does the alert comes up if you use a new browser everytime. ?

Comment: If by "new browser" you a new window or tab I guess it would be ideal. Not sure if has to be done one by one or if I can set it up to handle maybe 5 or 10 urls at a time. Since it's a large amount it would save a lot of time. 
The "allow notifications message" appears twice, the second time is after the first url has been loaded, login worked and landed on the home page. At this point the browser should close, reopen and proceed to next url. But the "allow notifications" pop up remains on screen and the script throws the error about the "inputpassword".

Comment: By adding the line 'driver.execute_script('window.open("{}", "_blank");'.format(url))' at the end after the 'login_box.click()' it opens again the first url from the 'mylist' in a new tab with the user already logged in and again stops at the "allow notifications" pop up with the same 'inputpassword' error. I don't know if it stops because it doesn't know how to handle the "allow notifications" pop up or if it's not being able to being to find the next url in 'mylist'.

Comment: yes, about the column name I figured that one out by trial and error.

Comment: You can do multi threading with chrome browser using drivers. that would be a another question.  If this solves your orginal problem/question, please accept and upvote. thanks.

Comment: Well, I'm still stuck being able to open only one url as I was when I first posted the question. The only thing that's changed it's that now all urls are in a list but it doesn't open the multiple urls. So I don't think it's resolved.